# How to reply to thank you from worker who takes orders in restaurant?

Tags: phrase-request

How to reply to "Thank you" from the man who takes orders from restaurants (like McDonalds), I'm not sure but are phrases "you're welcome" and "don't mention it" OK? They feel strange in this situation.

Comment: Usually, in such a situation, I will normally smile and nod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phrases like "you're welcome" and "don't mention it" are rarely inappropriate; they show friendly politeness, which is pretty much universally appreciated.

That said, when someone takes my order at a fast-food restaurant, and they say thank you, I often reply by saying, *"Thank you."*

This is not mere parroting; essentially, what is being said is:

> Employee: ***“Thank you [for your business].”***
>   Customer: ***“Thank you [for your service].”***

Comment: So it's like that both parties thank each other?

Comment: @Safira - That's not the _only_ way to do it, but it's one way to handle it with politeness.

Answer (score 1):

When someone says "thank you" after you placing your order, they just signal that they got your order.  No need to say anything. In my opinion answering "You are welcome" is out of place.